How can i achieve this letter
I'm new to this and I'm trying to get this letter (the one I show below), I want the rare F. I really don't know how to do it. I would be very grateful to anyone who can help me.


Welcome to TeX.SE! have you tried texify?

Welcome. // Have a look here: https://tug.ctan.org/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf . It provides symbols, the package to include and how to call your F-symbol.

$\mathcal{F}$

Wowww ty so much @MS-SPO :D

tyyyy @SandyG thats it
